# Interpretors of AIML 2.0

Tags: python-3.7, aiml

I am new to AIML 2.0 can any one suggest me the available interpretors that support AIML 2.0,and some useful resources.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [program-y](https://github.com/keiffster/program-y)

Answer (score 1):

Program AB also fully supports AIML 2 and was written by Dr Richard Wallace who invented AIML
https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/

A good resource for learning AIML is this free course:
https://www.udemy.com/course/artificial-intelligence-markup-language/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I’m the author of program-y. It’s fully aiml 2.1 compliant and 100% Python 3